# Akka, aggregate responses for a given request

Tags: akka

I'm starting to create a system with Akka. This system must resolve dependencies for a product. The dependencies are computed from two different sources.

```
class Deps extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Resolve(p) => 
     context.actorOf(System1.props) ! Resolve(p)
     context.actorOf(System2.props) ! Resolve(p)
  }
}
```

But it must aggregate the two responses in order to reply itself. Without any experience of Akka, I'm thinking of two solutions.

**1/ Maintain a `Map[(Product, Sender), Set[Response]]`**

Each time the `Deps` actor receive a `Response` from a child, it add the response to the set and if there is two responses it can create and send the response.

**2/ Create one `Actor` per `Product`**

The `Deps` actor is (or create a child actor that is) initialized with a `Product` as constructor parameter. It maintains two `var Option[Response]` and each time it receive a `Response` he verify if they are both present he can create and send the response.

I think this is the best approach but I have to maintains two `var` for the response and one for the *sender* so I'm not sure it is the best way to do.

**3/ Use `ask`**

Everything is described into the doc.

**4/ Use tell with a mutable "result"**

My actual code has already a `Report` that is update from the result of all sources. But I can use the same pattern as in Spray; I can pass the report as part of the message to all actors so that they can immediately update it so that I can really "fire and forget".

What is the usual way to wait and aggregate multiple response before replying to the sender from an actor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "aggregate multiple responses" by using the `flatMap` functionality of a `Future` which I think is best understood with a for-comprehension:

```
val fut1 : Future[Response] = 
  (context.actorOf(System1.props) ? Resolve(p)).mapTo[Response]

val fut2 : Future[Response] = 
  (context.actorOf(System2.props) ? Resolve(p)).mapTo[Response]

val comboFut : Future[(Response, Response)] = 
  for {
    resp1 <- fut1
    resp2 <- fut2
  } yield (resp1, resp2)
```

This Future can then be used with the [pipe pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2-RC1/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors):

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

comboFut pipeTo sender
```

Comment: Thanks. But here you are using the "ask" pattern. While it seems that "tell" is preferred.

Comment: Agreed that tell is preferred for performance reasons, but it would make the logic within your actor significantly more complicated.  With ask you can use the for-comprehension to aggregate the responses; with tell you would have to maintain state between multiple receive invocations.